# Nodemailer with Gmail

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gmail, nodemailer

I'm trying to implement contact form for my website using Nodemailer and Gmail, but unfortunately something is wrong. I can't find the issue. Below is my post route:

```js
app.post('/form', cors(), (req, res, next) => {

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: 'some.mail@gmail.com',
            pass: 'password'
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    const htmlEmail = `
        <h3>Contact Details</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Name: ${req.body.author}</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Message:</h3>
        <p>${req.body.body}</p>
    `

    let mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.author,
        to: 'some@mail.com',
        replyTo: req.body.author,
        subject: "Portfolio Website - Contact",
        text: req.body.body,
        html: htmlEmail
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.json({err: error});
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        res.redirect('form');
    });
});
```

And here is my HTML form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="form" accept-charset=utf-8>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea name="body" placeholder="Write an e-mail here..." class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Author" class="form-control author" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">    
      <input class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block" type="submit" value="Send" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

I will be greteful with any help!

Cheers,
Szymon

PS. Here is the link to the repo on GitHub:
https://github.com/alojzz/alojzz.github.io/blob/master/server.js

Comment: Try this.  While using Nodemailer. You will receive an email for less secure app on gmail account you are using. In this mail **Turn on access for this / less secured app**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i changed 'Less secure app access' in security of my google account to be 'on'. And that solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've tried it before and it still does not work, so the issue must be different than that.

Comment: not sure, but in your form tag, action shouldn't be this ' /form ' ?

Comment: the action looks fine, try pressing `send` from the snippet output code and you will see `Requested URL: /form`

Comment: Maybe the `smtp` port is not 465 but 587? can you try it? also there is a limit of 99 emails per day, make sure you didn't pass that.

Comment: Still the same. I've changed port and add res.send('form'); - nothing. I still get an error after clicking 'send' button in the form: File not found

Comment: Is your `app` code with the connection information in a file `form.php` ? if so, you have to add `action="form.php"` or the relevant file name (according to your error).

Comment: Nope, I didn't do that in PHP, but in Node.js.